# NGINX 'global' location

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to create a 'global' location for an NGINX server? I'd like every site served by NGINX to have access to a /global/ folder; along the lines of

```
http {
    [...stuff...]

    #Global path
    location /global/ {
        root /my/global/location/;
    }

    server {
        listen          127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name     example.com;

        [...standard config...]
    }

    server {
        listen          127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name     example.org;

        [...standard config...]
    }

    server {
        listen          127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name     example.net;

        [...standard config...]
    }
}
```

And be able to access files in the global location from http://example.com/global/ http://example.org/global/ etc.

I can do this if I add the global location block to every `server` block but that's annoying, I'd like to have it defined globally and be able to access it from within the sites.

I could use an `include` directive in each host, but it still requires specification in each host. The NGINX wiki says the 'location' block is only valid within the `server` context but I didn't know if there was a rewrite trick or something similar.

Comment: any update on this? ~4 years later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not no and as far as I know there isn't any talk of changing that either.

Comment: Thought so, but it was worth a try

Comment: Well that's depressing.

Answer (score 2):

What about just include it? e.g.

`include /etc/nginx/global-location.conf;`

I know you need to add it to each of the vhosts but it allows to do further changes easily and I think it is faster than having dynamic vhosts.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do it the other way round, by using dynamic vhost directories.
for example:

```
server {
...
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
...
    location /global/ {
        root /my/global/location/;
    }
...
```